# How to print for vertically for manual histogram without library(matplotlib,seaborn,etc)?

Tags: python, histogram

I have a list

```
a = ['book', 'pencil', 'pen', 'eraser', 'marker']       
c = [10,9,8,9,6]
```

I want the output to be

```
10 
*      9          9 
*      *     8    *       
*      *     *    *      
*      *     *    *      6    
*      *     *    *      *
*      *     *    *      *
*      *     *    *      *
*      *     *    *      *
*      *     *    *      *
*      *     *    *      *
book pencil pen eraser marker
```

But i don't know how to print it vertically, i tried this

```
for i in range (10):
    for j in range(len(c)):
        print("  *", end="   ")
    print(" ")
print(' '.join(a))
```

but the ouput is all 10 *, how to make the output i wanted?

Comment: See if you can come up with a rule that tells you whether to print the `*` in `"  *"`.

Comment: Counting down instead of up will also make life easier...

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['book', 'pencil', 'pen', 'eraser', 'marker']
c = [10, 9, 8, 9, 6]

print_list = []

for i in range(max(c), 0, -1):
    line = ""
    for j in c:
        if j >= i:
            line += "*"
        line += "\t\t"
    print_list.append(line)

line = ""
for i in a:
    line += i + ((8 - len(i)) * " ")

print_list.append(line)

for line in print_list:
    print(line)
```

output is

```
*                                       
*       *               *               
*       *       *       *               
*       *       *       *               
*       *       *       *       *       
*       *       *       *       *       
*       *       *       *       *       
*       *       *       *       *       
*       *       *       *       *       
*       *       *       *       *       
book    pencil  pen     eraser  marker
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way

```
c = [10,9,8,9,6]
high = max(c)
bars = [('*'*i).rjust(high) for i in c]
rows = [' '.join(i) for i in zip(*bars)]
print(*rows, sep='\n')
```

output

```
*
* *   *
* * * *
* * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
* * * * *
```

I used `zip` combined with `*` to execute transposition, which allows me to convert bars into rows for printing. Note that all `bars` are of equal length in order to allow transpose.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't use the value in `c` at any moment, you need them. I'd suggest the `i` loop goes backward from `10` (the max), so you can use it as a condition to know whether to print a space or a star

```
names = ['book', 'pencil', 'pen', 'eraser', 'marker']
values = [10, 9, 8, 9, 6]
mx = max(values)

for i in range(mx, -1, -1):
    for val in values:
        print("  *" if val > i else "   ", end="   ")
    print(" ")

print(' '.join(names))
```

---

For numbers on top of each bar

```
for i in range(mx, -1, -1):
    for val in values:
        if val == i:
            print(f"  {val}", end="   ")
        elif val > i:
            print("  *", end="   ")
        else:
            print("   ", end="   ")
    print()
```

Comment: next step, what if i want to print the values on the top of each *? `print("  *" if val > i else ([values[x] for x in range(len(values))] if i==val else "   "), end="   ")`.  i tried this in the line 7 but the output is all while i want one by one.

Comment: @c.jungc don't understand. Please edit your initial post to show exactly what you expect

Comment: i've edited the output in my post to the output i told earlier

Answer (score 0):

One easy Solution :

```
a = ['book', 'pencil', 'pen', 'eraser', 'marker']
c = [10, 9, 8, 9, 6]
d = max(c)

for i in range(d, -1, -1):
    for j in c:
        print("  *" if j > i else "   ", end="   ")
    print(" ")
print(' '.join(a))
```

output :

```
  *                            
  *     *           *          
  *     *     *     *          
  *     *     *     *          
  *     *     *     *     *    
  *     *     *     *     *    
  *     *     *     *     *    
  *     *     *     *     *    
  *     *     *     *     *    
  *     *     *     *     *    
book pencil pen eraser marker
```